# Properly feeding data into an LSTM from different trials

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, lstm

I am using pytorch to build an LSTM. The goal:

- Input a series of tensors and get a prediction for each tensor

My data:

- 100 videos. Each video is 100 seconds long has been split into 1 seconds chunks (at 24 fps). Each frame within each chunk is a `(224,224,3)` matrix. Total input data looks like this:

```
(100, 100, 24, 224, 224, 3)
- 100 videos
- 100 seconds per video
- 24 frames per chunk
- (224,224,3) tensor per frame
```

Each video measures the same thing so I can treat them all as input data. However, as they represent different trials, the sequential nature that occurs within each video does not continue across all videos. As a result, I don't want to join all of my data into 1 training set.

I believe I want to batch my data according to each video, such as 100 batches for 100 videos. Is this the right approach? I want the LSTM to `remember` sequential information within each video, but not across videos.

Will writing a custom DataLoader function with pytorch be the right thing to do, or is my understanding inadequate?